# if else in <dd></dd> tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have a fragment with vue js code. This code print some value.

```
              <dl>
                <!-- Fan speed -->
                <dt>{{ $t('pageInventory.table.fanSpeed') }}:</dt>
                <dd>{{ dataFormatter(item.speed) }}</dd>
              </dl>
```

But if I have value == -1 I should to print 0.
I write this code like in C style but it have a compilation error.

```
  <dd>{{ (item.speed != -1) ? dataFormatter(item.speed) : dataFormatter('0') }}</dd>
```

I have a error like this

```
error Replace {{·dataFormatter((item.speed·!=·-110)·?·item.speed·:·'0')·}} with ⏎··················{{·dataFormatter(item.speed·!=·-110·?·item.speed·:·'0')·}}⏎················
```

How I should it write. Help me pls!!!

Comment: Seems about correct, what error are you seeing?

Comment: error  Replace `{{·dataFormatter((item.speed·!=·-110)·?·item.speed·:·'0')·}}` with `⏎··················{{·dataFormatter(item.speed·!=·-110·?·item.speed·:·'0')·}}⏎················`  prettier/prettier

Comment: This is an error or a warning? This is pretty much ESlint compllaining. Try to setup it in your project. Or if you're using VScode, try `>ESlint: Fix all auto-fixable Problems` in your command palette (`ctrl + shift + p`).

Comment: Did you try the replacement?

Comment: Its a error: | ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Comment: Sorry but... I cannot get the relationship of the error message and your question body. I even cannot find `{{·dataFormatter((item.speed·!=·-110)·?·item.speed·:·'0')·}}` in your question body. And your reply's code style is really not pretty. You can put it in your question body please.

Comment: Either edit it yourself or let ESlint fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here, ESlint mainly complains because of your additional parenthesis here `(item.speed·!=·-110)` (you can notice it if you make a difference between your string and the one "required").
Still, you need to automate this to follow the guidelines of ESlint/Prettier rather than fixing it yourself every single time by making a diff.

Try to open your Command Palette if you're on VScode and run (`ctrl + shift + p`)

```
>ESlint: Fix all auto-fixable Problems
```

PS: of course you'll need the [VScode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) installed in your code editor.

---

You can of course set this one up to work on save with your code editor with the following (`settings.json`, acessible with Command palette + `>Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`)

```js
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": false,
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The expectation is that your ternary branches don't repeat the function call.    E.g.:

```js
// rewrite this
condition ? func(arg1) : func(arg2)

// into this
func(condition ? arg1 : arg2)
```

I would also suggest negating the condition for readability—it's easier for humans to follow this way.

As for the rest, rather than trying to apply formatting rules manually, it helps to let a formatter like Prettier do it for you.

Altogether, you get something like this:

```html
<dl>
  <!-- Fan speed -->
  <dt>{{ $t('pageInventory.table.fanSpeed') }}:</dt>
  <dd>
    {{ dataFormatter(item.speed === -1 ? '0' : item.speed) }}
  </dd>
</dl>
```